# pressing backspace once deletes everything in the uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autocomplete, uisearchbar

Hello I have a very strange bug: In a `UISearchBar` control if I press the backspace key on the keyboard, NOT the gray X on the textfield but the key on the onscreen keyboard, it deletes every character one by one. Just as if I pressed the key repeatedly until the text field is clear, but I only pressed it once.

Details:
I assume the problem lies in the the following two methods but I am not sure.

In a view I have 2 uisearchbar objects. In the view controller which is a `UISearchBarDelegate` i have a `textDidChange` method:

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
// called when text changes (including clear)
{
  [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
  debugLog(@"SearchViewController textDidChange");
  AutoCompleteViewController *acvc = [[AutoCompleteViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"AutoCompleteViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
  acvc.searchBar = searchBar;
  acvc.datasource = self;
  [self presentModalViewController: acvc animated:TRUE];
  [acvc release];
}
```

The class `AutoCompleteViewController` has another `UISearchBar` and a `UITableView`. This class also implements `UISearchBarDelegate` and in his textDidChange asks the delegate for a list of strings for the text entered in the `UISearchBar`.

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *) _searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
  debugLog(@"AutoCompleteViewController textDidChange");
  if (shouldReloadResults)
  {
    [autoCompleteValues release];
    autoCompleteValues = [datasource valuesForSearchString:self : _searchBar.text];
    [autoCompleteValues retain];

    [acResultsTable reloadData];
  }
}
```

So if I'm out in the main view and select a search bar and press backspace once, it deletes the first letter, shows the autocomplete view and then begins to delete every other character also showing the autocomplete results for each of them, until the search bar is empty. And I just pressed backspace once. I also have other methods but I think these are relevant but I have no idea what's wrong. If I'm already in the `AutoCompleteViewController` and then press backspace it works correctly.

UPDATE: So far i've figured out that calling `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` causes these odd behaviors. The problem is I set `becomeFirstResponder` for my autocomplete search bar so the user doesn't have to click it again after he enters the first letter. But it also causes the autocomplete search bar delete every character. I wonder if there is a way to detect the backspace character. It would solve my problems.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior in the UISearchField.

Comment: No, backspace on the iPhone on-screen keyboard does not delete everything if you press it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use 2 UISearchDisplayController objects. When the user begins the search in the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` method i create a search display controller and then in the `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` I release the search display controller. This is slightly simplified version i also use animations to move the second search bar to the top of the view before activating the search display controller for it.